# How to use mailto to send email with an attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html

How to use mailto to send email with an attachment

I have tried the below one:

```
<a href="mailto:a@gmail.com?subject=my report&body=see attachment&attachment=c:\myfolder\myfile.txt">
```

But it not worked.Can anybody assist how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Nope, this is not possible at all. There is no provision for it in the mailto: protocol, and it would be a gaping security hole if it were possible.

The best idea to send a file--

1.Have the user choose a file
2.Upload the file to a server
3.Have the server return a random file name after upload
4.Build a mailto: link that contains the URL to the uploaded file in the message body

Comment: If the uploaded file is there in server how to send as attachment using mail to?

Comment: If the Attachment is already in server then you have to give the path of that server file location in attachment parameter. I hope you have configured your mail server so that your mailto request knows about the mail server details (i.e. SMTP) for sending the mail. 

or

Comment: or In the Jump to URL, use the following string:
="MailTo:" + Fields!PPL_EMAIL_ADDR.Value + "?Subject=Test&attachment=” + Code.<functionName>()